# Error in parsing JSON to get another inside json value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a Json string that also contains another json sorrounded by scape characters.

Is there a way to parse or should I build a function to get this inside json?

```
data='[{"name":"JSON","value":"{\"Account\":\"94431714\"}]}","registerDate":"17-04-2020 16:37:37","comments":"Perfil de Promesa de Pago","profileType":"PROCESO_CRM","transactionId":"be3c5af4-0824-4c4d-bc5a-cfa3cfc32fb4"}]';
```

```
data2=JSON.parse(data);
```

And the value that I need is: `"{\"Account\":\"94431714\"}]}"`

Comment: The escaping is wrong so it is going to generate an error. You really need fix the code that generates this mess.

Comment: How did you do this escaping for inner json object?

Comment: Your object formation is wrong